# JS Image replacement on mouse click

Tags: javascript, effects

I’m new with JS and looking for any tips how to implment or even how can I replace a part of big image (that conisists of two smaller images) when you change some option on the sidebar for example when you change product parameters.

When you click either or “Kolor karnisza:” or “Wzór końcówki:” a part of image changes. Either the color of curtain rod or curtain rod end.

How can I achieve this, as far as I already learnt two images are positioned absolutely with z-index and I need some JS or jQuery library to do this effect (what library?).

This is the website I’m talking about:

https://www.sklep-karnisze.net/1136,-34-Carbonera-34-podwojne-proste-19-mm?r=#/#8,7,2,50,1,10,

Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<script>

  function changeImage(imgName)
  {
     image = document.getElementById('largepic');
     image.src = imgName;
  }

 </script>

 </head>

 <body>

      <img src = 'largemaimimage.jpg' id = 'largepic' />


         <img src ='small1.jpg' onClick="javaScript:changeImage('small1.jpg');"/>
         <img src ='small2.jpg' onClick="javaScript:changeImage('small2.jpg');"/>
         <img src ='small3.jpg' onClick="javaScript:changeImage('small3.jpg');"/>

  </body>
```

Many Times this is answered on this site

Comment: I think this will help me little but I rather looking for solution how to switch between multiple images on button click.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a plugin like pretty photo or lightbox, is that so ? so I can send you a link

Comment: http://fancybox.net/ Or http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ I would appreciate if you mark my answer as solution to your issue